# Two files with same name, in one directory

Tags: windows-7

When you change folder option setting in windows-7 in a way that you can see *System Files* and *Hidden Files*, then you can see two **Desktop.ini** files in desktop!

When I right-click on them and see properties, they have different location!

[image]

Note: When I select both and want to copy them in another folder, the below window, opens :

[image]

What is going on?

And how I can have another folder with this feature? (Having two files with equal name in it)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because the desktop is actually a type of virtual folder which consists of two folders. The folders are:

- %PUBLIC%/Desktop
- %HOMEPATH%/Desktop

If you type both of those in explorer then you can see the real file listings for each.

**Update**

If you would like to make folder which acts the same way you can use libraries. To do this type `Libraries` in the explorer address bar. Then right click anywhere in the view and select `New`. This will allow you to create a new library. To add folders to it right click it and select properties.

**Update 2**

You can have two files with the same name as long as one is in each folder. If you adjust the 'Arrange By' drop down you can even group them all together. This will lead to strange issues with sub folders though because those will also all be listed when not grouping by folder, for example:

[image: library showing by name view]

My library literally has 1,000s of those err.log files all listed together in this picture.

Comment: Thank you. Can I make a folder behave like Desktop? I mean: can I have a directory that consist of two folders?!(consist of files with equal name!)

Comment: @TheGoodUser-Sp See my update

Comment: But I still can't have two file with same name there!

Comment: @TheGoodUser-Sp See my update